# Closed form of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, summation, generating-functions

I'm trying to find a closed-form for
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{2^n}$$
on natural $k$.

First I look at $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=2$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}=2$. After that, I realized that I needed calculus to get further, so I took the generating functions approach with that.

I have used the generating function $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=f(x)$. Differentiating yields $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^2x^{n-1}=f'(x)$ and so $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^2x^n=xf'(x)$. Differentiating over and over again gives:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^kx^n=x^{k-1}f^{(k-1)}(x)$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^k}{2^n}=\frac{f^{(k-1)}\left(\frac12\right)}{2^{k-1}}.$$

From here, I was wondering if I could get more of a "closed-form" expression by finding a closed form for the term $f^{(k-1)}\left(\frac12\right)$ (remember that $f(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$). I differentiated it manually a few times but couldn't find a pattern. If there is a nice form, is there any easier way to find it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: https://www.math24.net/leibniz-formula#:~:text=The%20Leibniz%20formula%20expresses%20the,up%20to%20nth%20order.&text=The%20first%20derivative%20is%20described,%E2%80%B2v%2Buv%E2%80%B2.

Comment: See the first formula in the identities section ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number#Identities

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Thanks so much! Is there a proof for that identity?

Comment: This generating function is mentioned [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1909218p13073042)

Comment: The formula is probably quite easy to prove by induction & using the recurrence relation for the Eulerian numbers. ... You still need to calculate $A(\frac{1}{2})$ which can probably be done using the exponential generating function (mentioned at the beginning of the above wiki link)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent Phi function:

$$\Phi \left(\frac{1}{2},-k,0\right)$$

Comment: Thanks so much! I will look into the Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent Phi function (A doozy to write out)

Answer (score 2):

Let
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_k &=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{2^n} \\
F(x) &=& \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f_k \frac{x^k}{k!}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Inverting the order of the plums gives (use the exponetial sum & geometric sum formulea)
\begin{eqnarray*}
F(x)= \frac{1}{1-e^x/2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Half of this is the exponetial generating function of the Ordered Bell numbers see https://oeis.org/A000670

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It certainly seems faster than my approach.